# maximum limit for plotting lat-long on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

I want to highlight a route on google maps along with our network sites. I have successfully done it but when I load data in large proportion then my plugin becomes unresponsive. Can someone suggest me a way to avoid this error.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum.How much data you are uploading (and how?? through plugin or any wms url) ?

Comment: +1 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/QMHKn-oaB24 & http://support.google.com/mapsengine/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1272933

Comment: thanks for immediate response i have to load around 10000 locations on google map and its lat-long is read from an excel.i am using javascript. apart from these coordinates i also have some kml files to be uploaded, for which i am providing an url.

Comment: fusion tables would be faster and handle more than 10,000 points https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. I tried that link but want to import that table in google map

Comment: Instead of drawing 10.000 markers, you could try building a geoJSON file and loading it to the google.maps.data layer. It should be faster. However, 10.000 points is still a lot, and you're pretty close to what the browser can handle. On the other hand, 10.000 markers in a kml file shouldn't be a problem, if you can bear with kml layer limitations.